# Is there a version of JQuery 1.4.2. with Intellisense yet?

Tags: jquery, intellisense

Does anybody know how/when/why/who/where of if the JQuery intellisense files live for JQuery 1.4.2. On the Google Code pages the most up to date version that I can find is 1.3.2.

Comment: dup: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2323366/jquery-1-4-2-vsdoc

Comment: I didn't search for jquery-1.4.2-vsdoc. Guess that is why I never spotted it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's not available at the time of this answer, though the only difference since 1.4.1 vsdoc should be it missing the delegate method.

Use the 1.4.1 vsdoc, just know that [`.delegate()`](http://api.jquery.com/delegate/) and [`.undelegate()`](http://api.jquery.com/undelegate/) (wrappers for `.live()`) are also options available to you: http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.4.1-vsdoc.js

Comment: Thank you. I thought I would have to do that.

Answer (score 1):

Cross posting link so I can find this myself somewhat later:
[Updating JQuery 1.4.2 documentation yourself](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2323366/jquery-1-4-2-vsdoc/2515647#2515647). Hope this is of some use to you.

Answer (score 1):

I created one that is free to download:

http://hugeonion.com/2010/06/26/here-is-the-missing-jquery-1-4-2-vsdoc-file/