# vsdoc support for jQuery 1.4.3: how long?

Tags: jquery, visual-studio

jQuery was updated over the weekend. How long should I expect to wait before the .-vsdoc version is released?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Update:* [The appendTo guys](http://appendto.com/) have [made a jQuery 1.4.3 vsdoc available here](http://appendto.com/blog/2010/11/visual-studio-2010-vsdoc-jquery-143-now-available) ([direct link](http://appendto.com/community/vsdoc))

Also, [from Scott Guthrie](http://twitter.com/#!/scottgu/statuses/2857754834247680):

> Several people have asked about jQuery 1.4.3 vsdoc support in VS. We are working w/ jQuery team on automated solution to keep it up to date

---

*Previous answer:*
It'll probably be a while for the official version, since the 1.4.2 version was never released either ([status updated here from ScottGu saying he's looking into it](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/10/04/jquery-templates-data-link-and-globalization-accepted-as-official-jquery-plugins.aspx#7623375) - search comments).  Note that this falls officially on the MS team, not the jQuery team to provide.

However the community should have a version (maybe in response to this question) quicker than that, see [this version for 1.4.2 as an example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2323366/jquery-1-4-2-vsdoc).

Comment: Thankx...I think i'll use the 'rename to match current' method to see what breaks? I'm not needing intellisense for the new stuff for the time being.

Comment: appendTo guys still make the vsdoc available and update it to work with latest jquery version. The easiest way to get it is to use Install-Package jquery.vsdoc or Update-Package if you already have older vsdoc in your project.