# jQuery 1.4.3 vsdoc

Tags: jquery, visual-studio, vsdoc

Does anybody know where I can get the vsdoc for jQuery 1.4.3? Alternatively, what changes do I need to make to jQuery 1.4.2 vsdoc file to add the new functions in 1.4.3?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can find it here : http://appendto.com/community/vsdoc

Comment: as a sidenote, this site now has the 1.4.4 release

Answer (score 1):

this page contain a list of vsdoc files on microsoft's CDN

http://www.asp.net/ajaxlibrary/cdn.ashx

just search for vsdoc and u will find it :)

right now its not on official jquery download page

Answer (score 0):

what thing you exactly need. if you want to work with Jquery you can still use 1.4.2 version.
if you want to work with 1.4.3 then you can also use jquery file who you obtained from jquery.com

i thing you need to work with 1.4.3

so for great intellisense place 1.4.2 vsdoc file to page and when you deploy the website then place their Google API for jquery 1.4.3