# Produce "toast" messages like StackOverflow

Tags: .net, asp.net, jquery, ajax, messagebox

One of the issues I think about every time I build my web application is how messages  should appear to the end-users

I tried message boxes like those in windows applications, but they look so bad and make problems when published on the server. I've tried an update panel containing a cool label at the top of bottom of my page..but still i feel it's not good enough at all. Sometimes I have problems in specific cases when using AJAX, and it still doesn't look good for the users...

I want to ask about the StackOverFlow messages that appear for a while and then disappear, for example the message that appears in orange when voting a message up or down.

I want to build messages like these or reuse a DLL that can provide these. Is this feasible?

note:::
the messages appeared for the user based on specific condition on the server side..

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You might want to reword your title at the very least. Currently it's ambiguous and might lead to the question being migrated (incorrectly) to [Meta](http://meta.stackoverflow.com)

Comment: feel free to edit my question,, iam not that good in English, i just try to give my question idea..thanks

Comment: As far as the jQuery warning, see here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2323366/jquery-1-4-2-vsdoc it's just related to intellisense in the IDE

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Well, one method to use jGrowl (to expand on Shane's Answer) via .cs is shown below.

This example in webform ASP.NET

Create a simple aspx page with 1 button and make sure you include the necessary jquery/jgrowl script and css references in the page head, I also have a ScriptManager and update panel on the page as well.

In the code behind for the page:

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.ShowStatus("This is your message!<br />Some HTML formatting works!<br />");
}

protected void ShowStatus(string message)
{
    ScriptManager sm = ScriptManager.GetCurrent(Page);

    if (sm.IsInAsyncPostBack)
    {
        string script = @"
            $(document).ready(function() {
            $.jGrowl.defaults.theme = 'iphone';
            $.jGrowl('" + message + "', {theme: 'iphone',header: 'Notification',life: 8000});});";

        ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(Page,this.GetType(), "notification", script,true);                        
    }
}
```

Naturally use whatever theme suits your app, good luck! Additionally, this approach only loads the notification script as needed (in this case after you click the button) but you could tie the "ShowStatus" function to other events/tests within the code behind.

Comment: please can u explain the method u write::especially the parts u use script manger in i want to know how it works please..thank u so much

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb310408.aspx for more info on RegisterStartupScript, and http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.scriptmanager.aspx for ScriptManager itself, the explain the idea behind how and why they work.

Comment: what does/or doesn't? The app I pulled this from runs just fine in IE/FF/Chrome....what is giving you an issue?

Comment: @user418343> whats your firefox version?

Comment: do you have any funny plug-ins/ add-ins active in Firefox?

Comment: sorry it works ,, i open a new project and begin from scratch,,i donot know what is the problem in the previous one but it works thank u so much..

Answer (score 17):

Specifically, the [jGrowl](http://stanlemon.net/pages/jgrowl) jQuery plugin does what you're asking.

Just include the jQuery and jGrowl scripts in your html, and start generating messages with the $.jGrowl() function.

Example code:

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="path/to/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="path/to/jgrowl.js"></script>
<script>
$(function() {
  $.jGrowl("My sticky message, loaded after the rest of the page", {sticky: true});
  $("#mybutton").live("click", function(_) {
    $.jGrowl("you clicked the button!");});
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<button id="mybutton">click me</button>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: thanks alot, but how to use them in .cs file or .aspx , can u give me simple example.

Comment: example provided. I haven't worked with .NET, but from what I read online it's fairly straightforward to include something like the above in your .aspx template.

Comment: +1 Good call on jGrowl, it works nicely, added my own answer with .NET/.cs example

Answer (score 12):

To create effects you can use these tools

[Jquery](http://jqueryui.com)

**jQuery** user interface library. It provides interactions, widgets, effects, and theming for creating Rich Internet Applications

you can view some Jquery effects [here](http://api.jquery.com/category/effects/)

[MooTools](http://mootools.net)

A web applications user interface library built on the Mootools JavaScript framework

Comment: The typical SO answer: Use Jquery!

Comment: What other answer do you expect someone to provide? Feel free to provide a better alternative. Until then... jQuery rocks!

Comment: @MaximGershkovich I would (if I was the person asking) how to use JQuery to achieve this, i.e. is there a plugin or example of this in action.  Just stating you can use JQuery is a bit like saying you can get a bus to X but not saying which one or where to get it from.  Regards

Answer (score 2):

Another very nice  a JavaScript notification plugin is [Pines Notify](http://pines.hg.sourceforge.net/hgweb/pines/pnotify/raw-file/tip/index.html)

It features also a notification history widget.

Comment: this is great one ,, but how to use with .cs file i wanna to show this message when the user click on server button in asp.net..thanks alot..i hope it works with IE and firefox..

Comment: this looks so nice ,,, then how to use it in .cs file ... i search on this site , and cannot find how to use them ..

Answer (score 1):

Notimoo plugin using mootools.
Used just yesterday, and liked the configuration options.

http://code.google.com/p/notimoo/