# how to use jquery in the codebehind of asp.net web application

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, jquery, ajax

Q:many times , i find my self need some features ,and when search and search i find all i need as jquery files , i donot know jquery , all i know that it is javascript library ,now i wanna to know if i have set of jquery files , after including those files in any asp.net application . how to use them ,i mean how to use their functions in the .cs(code behind) file..if there is an example to understand the main idea, it will be great.

thanks in advance

Comment: You can't use javascript in your codebehind (managed code).

Comment: but i see some code use jquery functions in the codebehind ,, for example , if i wanna to show a specific message (this message with jquery)based on button click event.

Comment: no, Yves is right. all javascript runs in the browser on the clients machine

Comment: this an example but i need more explanation to this issue..http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4237636/produce-toast-messages-like-stackoverflow.

Comment: I don't want to be rude, but there are some very simple and fundamental principles that you are not understanding here. I would suggest that you read up on the asp.net model, and specifically the differences between server and client. also read up on javascript.

Comment: i know that the java script is a client side script and so the jquery  works only on the client side .. just i have a specific case in the link i posted before ..i wanna to show a specific message this message based on the user click ..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

JQuery is for HTML Manipulation (and animation, event handling and Ajax) on the client so you won't be able to use it in your code behind but only on the client !

Now using JQuery is simply adding a reference to it in your html like

`<script src="path to jquery.js" type="text/jajascript"></script>`

then the js file will be loaded on the client and you will be able to use the JQuery object often used with its alias $.

Follow [this tutorial](http://www.authenticsociety.com/blog/jQueryPluginTutorial_Beginner) and you should be on track in 18 minutes

For your popup problem, you can find a lot of popup plugins here : http://plugins.jquery.com/

Comment: @Yves M:Sorry, my hands was typing too fast ;-)

Answer (score 1):

there are some great tutorials on [the jQuery site](http://jquery.com/)

Answer (score 1):

Jquery can be a very useful extra functionality for your application, it will work clientside as you must have realized from your finding that it is a JavaScript library.

I often integrate it with .net applications and that works great. I generally just add it in the aspx-file, not in code-behind, but that should be possible too, if needed, by using the  ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock-functionality.

JQuery is very well documented. Take a look at http://docs.jquery.com/Tutorials 
When you get the basics, you will soon get the point how and if you can use it for your features.

Answer (score 1):

The example you link to shows somebody using the ScriptManager class to output script to the client, where it runs.

This is a tool that ASP.net provides to simplify outputting dynamic `<script>` tags - it does not run the javascript on the server at all.