# How to show a label message, then hide it after some seconds?

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I would like to show a message on my ASP.Net page like "Record saved" on save button click. After 5 seconds, I would like to hide it.
How can I do in JavaScript? Can I avoid to add jQuery (I'm not using it)?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You could use the [`setTimeout`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/window.setTimeout) function which allows you to defer the execution of a callback in the future. So you could place the following in the page:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    window.setTimeout(function() {
        // This will execute 5 seconds later
        var label = document.getElementById('IdOfTheElementYouWantToHide');
        if (label != null) {
            label.style.display = 'none';
        }
    }, 5000);
</script>
```

Due to ID name mangling with ASP.NET you could use a [class selector](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1933602/how-to-getelementbyclass-instead-of-getelementbyid-with-javscript/1933623#1933623). And once you start doing this and your users start to ask you about adding some fade out effects you will quickly realize that a framework such as jQuery might come in handy.

Comment: @stighy: Remember, in order to get the control ID to pass to Javascript you must use the label's ClientId property :)

Answer (score 3):

You can use  a JavaScript notification plugin  [Pines Notify](http://pines.hg.sourceforge.net/hgweb/pines/pnotify/raw-file/tip/index.html)

Look at that [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4237636/produce-toast-messages-like-stackoverflow) to more choices

Answer (score 1):

You can use the jGrowl add-in for jQuery - this provides "Mac-style" notifications for this kind of scenario.