# javascript confirmation box?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, messagebox

```
Public Function CheckIfItemPresent(ByVal userID As String, ByVal itemID As String, ByVal itemPrice As Integer, ByVal offer As String) As Boolean
        On Error GoTo galti

        Dim sqlStatement As String = "SELECT itemQtty FROM shoppingCart WHERE userID = '" & _
                                    userID & "' AND itemID = '" & itemID & "'" & _
                                    " AND itemPrice = " & itemPrice & " AND offer = '" & offer & "'"
        Dim con As New SqlClient.SqlConnection("Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;" & _
                                               "AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\database.mdf;" & _
                                               "Integrated Security=True;User Instance=True")
        Dim sql As New SqlClient.SqlCommand(sqlStatement, con)
        Dim reader As SqlClient.SqlDataReader

        con.Open()
        reader = sql.ExecuteReader
        reader.Read()
        Dim itemQtty As Integer = reader.Item("itemQtty")
        reader.Close()
        If itemQtty > 0 Then
            If ***MsgBox("Item already present. Add another one? Currently, number of this item in cart: " & itemQtty, MsgBoxStyle.YesNo, "") = MsgBoxResult.Yes*** Then
                itemQtty = itemQtty + 1
                sql.CommandText = "UPDATE shoppingCart SET itemQtty = " & itemQtty & " WHERE " & _
                                    "userID = '" & userID & "' AND itemID = '" & itemID & "' AND itemPrice=" & _
                                    itemPrice & " AND offer = '" & offer & "'"
                sql.ExecuteNonQuery()
            Else
            End If
        End If
        con.Close()
        con.Dispose()
        Return True
        Exit Function
galti:
        con.Close()
        con.Dispose()
        Return False
    End Function
```

how to use javascript conformation box instead of asp.net msgbox...please check the portion in between ***

Comment: You have a SQL injection vulnerability.

Comment: You should close your connection with a `Using` block.

Comment: what is SQL injection vulnerability??? what is a `Using` block???how to use it??

Comment: http://unixwiz.net/techtips/sql-injection.html

Comment: possible duplicate of [MessagBox on JavaScript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6008130/messagbox-on-javascript)

Comment: no its not a duplicate...check it out first...and if u can provide an answer...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no drop-in replacement to do that with Javascript.

To interact with the user you have to send a response back to the browser that it can display, then the user can make the choise and send another request to the server containing the information about the choise.

So, you have to divide this into two separate steps on the server side.

To make a confirmation box in Javascript you can use the `confirm` method. Example:

```
var choise = window.confirm('Item already present. Add another one? Currently, number of this item in cart: 42');
```

Comment: if i use asp.net msgbox ..it does not pop up in the client side after i publish the website...wat to do???

Comment: @Monodeep: There is no ASP.NET MsgBox. The method only works when the server computer and client computer is the same computer, i.e. only when you are testing locally.