# How do I replace VS2010 javascript files

Tags: javascript, asp.net, jquery, visual-studio-2010

How do I update visiual studio 2010 Javascript files( jquery-1.4.1.*.js) with current jQuery.1.4.4

Essentially what I want is to pull in new version of js (1.4.4) when I create new ASP.Net Web Application etc.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's as easy as deleting the old jQuery from your project and dropping in the new jQuery files. Just head over to [jQuery.com and download the version](http://docs.jquery.com/Downloading_jQuery) that you want. In addition, as Brian pointed out, there are documentation updates included as well, so you can get things like Intellisense with jQuery in a .NET environment.

Another alternative is, if you do not need to ship jQuery with your project, [link to the Google CDN](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1447184/microsoft-cdn-for-jquery-or-google-cdn). This way, you'll automatically receive updates and you won't have to worry about keeping it up-to-date yourself. There are many advantages to CDN, but in some environments its not possible to use it (such as on an intranet application). You'll have to decide for yourself.

Answer (score 1):

JQuery was hosting these on their web site.  However, I just checked, and 1.4.1 is the last supported version from Microsoft.  Users have been adding documentation, for instance, see this: [jQuery 1.4.2 VSDoc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2323366/jquery-1-4-2-vsdoc)

You may be able to find something for 1.4.4.

HTH.