# Is there a VSDoc file for jQuery 1.5?

Tags: jquery, visual-studio, documentation, jquery-1.5

Where can I find a VSDoc file for the 1.5 version of jQuery?

Comment: When available, you'll see a link beside "Documentation" on the official jQuery download page @ http://docs.jquery.com/Downloading_jQuery.  I too am anxiously waiting!

Comment: Actually, as noted in the various answers to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2323366/jquery-1-4-2-vsdoc, Zack's response is *not* the case. For whatever reason, jQuery.com does not seem to be listing the vsdoc locations any longer (for new releases).

Comment: @Zachary: you still waiting? no need to, guys from appendTo picked up where MS left the dev community - see http://appendto.com/community/jquery-vsdoc

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It seems there is a VSDoc for jQuery 1.5 available at :

http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-1.5-vsdoc.js

Comment: ...or you can go to the original source here: http://appendto.com/community/jquery-vsdoc

Answer (score 5):

I haven't tested this exhaustively, but [I built a jQuery 1.5 VSDoc](http://encosia.com/2011/02/04/a-vsdoc-for-jquery-1-5/) that seems to work pretty well, other than handling the new jqXHR and Deferred return types.  So, you'll get the new Intellisense on `$.ajax()`, for example, but you won't get Intellisense for the new chained callbacks.

It should be better than nothing though, for now.

Comment: Thanks, this'll work great until the "official" one is up and running.

Comment: Damian made a fully functional version this evening, which handles the Deferred/jqXHR issues correctly.  I updated my post with a link to it.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is a vsdoc file available for jQuery 1.5 right now.

Answer (score 0):

Get latest releases of jQuery .vsdoc files on [Microsoft Ajax Content Delivery Network](http://www.asp.net/ajaxlibrary/cdn.ashx)

and jQuery intelliSense schema patch for Visual studio 2008 SP1 on Microsoft [KB958502 - JScript Editor support](http://archive.msdn.microsoft.com/KB958502/Release/ProjectReleases.aspx?ReleaseId=1736)